# Matlab computation Vs 'C/C++' computation..Which one is efficient?

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I have some mathematical algorithms implemented in Matlab. I have implemented those algorithms in C++ (i used Microsoft VS 2005). When i compare matlab code output with C++ code output, it is 98 to 99% matches with matlab output. Shouldn't it be 100% matched?
Is the matlab computation efficiency is better than C/C++?

Comment: What exactly did you compare?

Comment: by "efficiency" you mean faster? or more correct precision wise?

Comment: There are too many things that can be different to provide an answer. Slight differences in the implementation might produce different rounding errors, compiler flags might allow for more lenient or more strict evaluation of operations (i.e. tradeoff speed/accuracy) the algorithms in libraries might have completely different implementations...

Comment: What i meant is which one is more precise?

Comment: Why is this getting voted down so heavily? Sure, it's a very broad question, but the fundamental question makes good sense and isn't immediately intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no, Matlab will not produce more exact results just because it is Matlab. However, there is a number of things that might make a difference:

1. Different implementations of the same algorithm might have been written with different numerical stability in mind.
2. C and C++ compilers generally allow you to set compilation flags to do fast math, which changes floating-point math behaviour.
3. The output options for floating point numbers might just differ, making results *look* different.
4. The Matlab and C version might have used different floating point precisions.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab also there would be appropriate compiler so in this scenario its hard to say 
that   `matlab computation efficiency is better than C/C++`

if your code is same in both case then there should be same output. If you found some differences between   them them its should be because of their compiler version difference.